# Display RGB database foreground/background combinations

Tags: x11, colors

I'm trying to adjust color in X.  I seem to recall that there are a couple of utilities available to experiment with foreground/background combination while displaying all the colors.  Anybody know where such a thing can be found?

Answer (score 0):

I remembered the package ... it is called xcolorsel.